# Doors disappear from AutoCAD file when imported into QGIS

Tags: layers, autocad

I have a .dwg CAD drawing of a hospital floor. When I convert the file to .dfx and drag it into QGIS the doors are no longer visible. The walls show up fine.

Comment: Do you mean dxf? What geometry type are the doors? Are they blocks or individual lines or polygons? Are they on a layer that is frozen or turned off?  How are you converting the file? Are you sure they aren't white and not visible against the background? Please edit your question with more information so it can be reopened.